# Programmatically make clicks on a webpage

Tags: c#, javascript, automation, webbrowser-control

There is a onmousedown event on a webpage. I want to be able to have this event called from my app and have the WebBrowser object move to that page.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hmm, trying to make quick bucks buddy? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, you can't do this.  This is because the javascript is a client side technology and to accomplish what javascript does on your client you're going to have to pretend to be a client: you'll need to rebuild the entire document object model and execute the javascript that way.

You can reference this ticket where I tried solving a similar issue (calling javascript from within a PHP script): [Can a php proxy script call javascript functions like click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221466/can-a-php-proxy-script-call-javascript-functions-like-click)

Maybe if you explain the problem domain a little more, you'll discover that you don't even need the javascript all-together!  What are you trying to accomplish and why is the javascript required?  Good luck!

Comment: I've figured out an alternate solution but this one would be much easier.  I am the client, I have a Webbrowser object in a windows form, so shouldn't I be able to fake a mouse click?  I also found this as a solution http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=321029 but it seems very very sloppy.

Comment: You can't fake a button click but you can post/get data to wherever the button would send data to if you clicked it.

Comment: what about this http://www.megasolutions.net/cSharp/Invoking-Javascript-Functions-from-an-Instance-of-Internet-Explorer-69881.aspx#as_umsgid=1180506015.296910.258490@g37g2000prf.googlegroups.com 

I haven't had time to test it out but it looks promising

Answer (score 0):

The [`WebBrowser.Document`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document.aspx) property gives you an [`HtmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9bt3dad.aspx) object, which has an [`InvokeScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be9zzz62.aspx) method. I have used this before to execute JavaScript from a `WebBrowser` control. Frankly, it's an atrociously messy way to get something done, but it has worked for me. Could that be of use to you, maybe?

Comment: Ok, how would I point it to a specific mousedown event, there are multiple ones per page.

Answer (score 0):

gnucom's right.

Perhaps not the solution you are looking for: http://watir.com/examples/
It's Ruby based and but you could have your app interact with that perhaps...